# Repeat same label of the table from previous frame

Tags: tables, beamer

I am working on a presentation and would like to reuse the same table with the same label from the previous frame. I tried a lot of things, but did not have success. Attached u can find the frames and the code. 
Many thanks in forward.

[image: frames]

```
\section{Conceptual Framework}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{2. Conceptual Framework}

\begin{table}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player 2}\\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} \\\cline{3-4}
      \multirow{2}*{Player 1}  & C & $b-c, b-c$ & $-c, b$ \\\cline{3-4}
      & D & $b, -c$ & $0, 0$ \\\cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular} 
\caption{Prisoners' Dilemma}
\label{PD}
    \end{table}

\begin{itemize}
\item{$b$ $>$ $c$ $>$ $0$}
\item{Given $c$ $>$ $0$, it is a dominant strategy to play D}
\item{Hence the NE of this game is (D,D) with payoff ($0$,$0$)}
\item{Since (C,C) gives $b$ - $c$ $>$ $0$, the equilibrium outcome (D,D) is inefficient}
\end{itemize}   
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{2. Conceptual Framework}
\begin{table}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player 2}\\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} \\\cline{3-4}
      \multirow{2}*{Player 1}  & C & $b-c, b-c$ & $-c, b$ \\\cline{3-4}
      & D & $b, -c$ & $0, 0$ \\\cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular}
    \renewcommand\thetable{\ref{PD}} 
    \caption{Prisoners' Dilemma}    
    \addtocounter{table}{-1}    

    \end{table}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: The syntax for items should be `\item Given $c$ $>$ $0$, it is a dominant strategy to play D` (without the `{}` around)

Answer (score 1):

In the following MWE, I have moved the line `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` before the caption in the second frame. That will cause both tables on both frames to be numbered using the same number.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}

    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

    \begin{document}

    \section{Conceptual Framework}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2. Conceptual Framework}

    \begin{table}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
        \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player 2}\\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} \\\cline{3-4}
          \multirow{2}*{Player 1}  & C & $b-c, b-c$ & $-c, b$ \\\cline{3-4}
          & D & $b, -c$ & $0, 0$ \\\cline{3-4}
        \end{tabular} 
    \caption{Prisoners' Dilemma}
    \label{PD}
        \end{table}

    \begin{itemize}
    \item $b$ $>$ $c$ $>$ $0$
    \item Given $c$ $>$ $0$, it is a dominant strategy to play D
    \item Hence the NE of this game is (D,D) with payoff ($0$,$0$)
    \item Since (C,C) gives $b$ - $c$ $>$ $0$, the equilibrium outcome (D,D) is inefficient
    \end{itemize}   
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2. Conceptual Framework}
    \begin{table}

        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
        \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player 2}\\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} \\\cline{3-4}
          \multirow{2}*{Player 1}  & C & $b-c, b-c$ & $-c, b$ \\\cline{3-4}
          & D & $b, -c$ & $0, 0$ \\\cline{3-4}
        \end{tabular}
        \addtocounter{table}{-1} %<-------------------------- 
        \caption{Prisoners' Dilemma}      
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Alternatively you might be interested in using overlays for repeating the table on a second slide. This way, you only have to specify the code for the table once (which will  bea easier if you want to change the contents of the table)  and there will be no 'jumping'  of the table if you change from the first to the second slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\section{Conceptual Framework}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{2. Conceptual Framework}

\onslide<1-2>{
\begin{table}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player 2}\\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} \\\cline{3-4}
      \multirow{2}*{Player 1}  & C & $b-c, b-c$ & $-c, b$ \\\cline{3-4}
      & D & $b, -c$ & $0, 0$ \\\cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular} 
\caption{Prisoners' Dilemma}
\label{PD}
    \end{table}}

\onslide<1-1>{
\begin{itemize}
\item $b$ $>$ $c$ $>$ $0$
\item Given $c$ $>$ $0$, it is a dominant strategy to play D
\item Hence the NE of this game is (D,D) with payoff ($0$,$0$)
\item Since (C,C) gives $b$ - $c$ $>$ $0$, the equilibrium outcome (D,D) is inefficient
\end{itemize} }  
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```